# Learning C# delegates. Passing a filtering function as delegate

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

in my `Program.cs`

I declare a delegate

```
public delegate bool FilterDelegate(Employee emp);
```

I create a list of employees

```
 List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>
 {
               new Employee(){ID= 1907, Name= "Mary Sue", Experience = 5},
               new Employee(){ID= 1353, Name= "Peggy Sue",  Experience = 1},
               new Employee(){ID= 1645, Name= "Gary Stu", Experience = 2},
               new Employee(){ID= 141, Name= "John Doe", Experience = 3},
               new Employee(){ID= 1033, Name= "Jimmy Smith",  Experience = 4}
      };
```

call the displaying function and passthe delegate

```
Employee.FilterAndDisplay(employees, cutOffFilter);


static bool cutOffFilter(Employee emp)
{

    return emp.Experience < 4;
}
```

in `Employee.cs`

```
public static void FilterAndDisplay(List <Employee> employees, FilterDelegate filter)
{
    var table = new ConsoleTable("ID", "Name", "Experience");

    foreach (var emp in employees)
    {
        if(filter(emp))
        {
            table.AddRow(emp.ID, emp.Name, emp.Experience);
        }
       
    }


    table.Write();
    Console.WriteLine(); 
}
```

Now this works fine as it is. But what if I want to make  the number of years experience dynamic? How do I pass a variable to `static bool cutOffFilter` ? and then use it in  `if(filter(emp))` ?

Comment: Are you sure that work? The delegate expects two parameters, but the method `cutOffFilter` has one.

Comment: Maybe just my opinion, but I find delegate types a bit annoying to work with. `Func`s and `Action`s are easier in usage and more flexible.

Comment: @vernou The second on was a mistake

Comment: As a complete aside, `Employee` should be just the class which has the properties of an employee. It should not know anything at all about how to filter, or display employees. So move that method elsewhere!

Comment: @Jamiec sometime in database models don't they have methods to filter data?

Comment: @SaiKrishna No, not the DTO itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LambdaExrpessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) for this:
This assumes your delegate has only argument. Your example isnt clear there.

```
Employee.FilterAndDisplay(employees, emp => emp.Expirience < 2);
```

or

```
Employee.FilterAndDisplay(employees, emp => 
{
    return emp.Experience < 4;
});
```

or

```
int minExp = 5;
Employee.FilterAndDisplay(employees, emp => emp.Expirience < minExp );
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Linq.

Add a reference at the top to include System.Linq then use Where rather than your own filter method:

```
using System.Linq
```

...

```
foreach (Employee emp in employees.Where(e => e.Experience < 4))
    table.AddRow(emp.ID, emp.Name, emp.Experience);
```

...

So you can change your method to:

```
public static void FilterAndDisplay(List <Employee> employees, Func<Employee, bool> predecate)
{
    var table = new ConsoleTable("ID", "Name", "Experience");

    foreach (var emp in employees.Where(predecate))
        table.AddRow(emp.ID, emp.Name, emp.Experience);

    table.Write();
    Console.WriteLine(); 
}
```

...

If you still want the static function with param:

```
static bool CutOffFilter(Employee emp, int maxExp)
{
    return emp.Experience < maxExp;
}
```

And call your filter method as:

```
FilterAndDisplay(employees, e => CutOffFilter(e, 4));
```